# Php web-scraping divs with class do not display images

Tags: php, image, class, web-scraping, display

I'm web-scraping a newspaper online, external url, with this plane php, a class `block__item`, which is compose of other classes and images

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 
$url = "https://www.repubblica.it";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
@$doc->loadHTML($content);


    $classname="block__item";
    $finder = new DomXPath($doc);
    $spaner = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");


foreach ($spaner as $value) {
    echo $doc->saveXML($value);
   }
/?>
```

Now, images are not displayed; I have the space in the page, the url, but I can't see the image.

I tried with this

```
$images = $finder->query("(//img/@src)");
foreach ( $images as $image) {
    $print = $doc->saveXML($image);
    echo $print;
}
```

and this gave me all the images at the end of the page;
I tried with combine

```
foreach (array_combine($spaner, $images) as $value => $image){
    echo $value, $image;
   }
```

but I receive error.
I tried also with *query* class and img in the same time, but nothing.

Please, anyone could help me?

Comment: I’m not clear on your problem. Are you scraping a third party website and showing that HTML on your site, and there’s images that are missing? If so, inspect the HTML on your site fir the problem. The images are probably either relative (`../`) or absolute to the site root but without a domain (`/`), or the third party is blocking images using a referral policy.

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks! You understood perfectly!
I have this`<div class="block__item"><article><figure><a href="https://www.repubblica.it/article"<picture><source data-srcset="https://www.repstatic.it/content/nazionale/img/2022/06/17/1435c2.jpg?webp" media="(max-width: 767px)" type="image/webp"><img class="lazyload" data-src="https://www.repstatic.it/content/nazionale/img/2022/06/17/143548b.jpg" height="333" width="593"></picture></a></figure></article></div>`. I tried with your ideas but I had no result!

Comment: When I manually go to `https://www.repstatic.it/content/nazionale/img/2022/06/17/143548b.jpg` I get a 404, too. There isn't much you can do about that unless you can coordinate with the host directly.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thanks! Really! Actually the complete url is `https://www.repstatic.it/content/nazionale/img/2022/06/17/180010001-7feeb1a1-40b9-424d-b99a-cd6513168992.jpg`. I'm trying to scrape the `data-src` of the `<img>`, but I found nothing in this site that I can modify.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the issue is, but you can target the `img` tag and then call `getAttribute` on it: https://3v4l.org/trEK5#v8.1.7

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thanks again! I don't want to bore you; btw the issue is to display all the divs with `block__item`. At the moment I'm able to display all the divs, but I cannot display the images IN the divs at the same time.

Comment: I'm not sure what all to tell you. The HTML which you've posted 404's for me (although in two different ways, which is interesting). Hosting content on your site that is served by another site is always problematic. When someone visits your site, that site is being reported back to the origin site in the referrer header, so it is entirely possible that you are being blocked in that fashion. It is generally better in the long run to scrape server-side and download assets locally.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Okay! Thanks! Just in case this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/6vbdpwLx/1/) are some divs with class `block__item`; I can display correctly all the text, but not the images.